# Wrong date format when i create an event in google calendar

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I use a google form to create event in my calendar. The date format recorded on my spreadsheet is European DD/MM/YYYY but at the event creation google calendar put the date info in the Us format MM/DD/YYYY. So, events are displayed in my calendar at the wrong dates...

Ive check my gsuite account, drive, sheet are set to the right language and timezone (FRANCE / PARIS).
can you help me ?
Thx.

ex. MR ZAZOU 2th March -----> 4th Feb

[image: spreadsheet DD/MM/YYYY format]

[image]

EDIT: last code i use to create event

```
function createEvent_ (namedValues) {
  //options are the key/value pairs you can set when created a 
  //calendar event, below accesses the data given for description 
  //and location - guest is hard coded
var options = { description: namedValues.Description[0],
ocation: namedValues.Location[0],
              guests:"exemple"};
  //cEvent makdes the calendar event, You have to choose the calendar 
  //name that you would like to use, then ask for the Name of the event, 
  //start date and end date, then passes the options you have selected above
  var cEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("Example")[0].createEvent(
              namedValues.Name[0], 
              new Date(namedValues.Starts), 
              new Date(namedValues.Ends), 
              options)

}
```

Comment: You can define a timezone when creating the event. From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date)):
"If no time zone is specified, the time values are interpreted in the context of the script's time zone, which may be different than the calendar's time zone."
It might also help to post your code.

Comment: @nehalem Ive use differents way to do this, last i use the code from chatasweetie [link](https://github.com/chatasweetie/google-form-email-calendar/blob/master/script.js) Even i use the chain app maker Zappier, the result is the same...

Comment: Using Zaper ive also try to format date to MM/DD/YYYY but its not working.

Comment: Have you checked the time zone settings in your Google Script project?

Comment: Can you share the form that you are using to get the details of any event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it !
The problem was from the google form addon "Form publisher". Ive add an extra date field in my form for testing. In the form editor, the date format showed by google is the right one, but when i explore the template option of Form publisher, the format was named with wrong format.